# LayoutManager for RecyclerView to set the number of columns automatically according to width of items

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to build a UI involving RecyclerView or GridView, where i want to set the number of columns automatically depending upon the number and width of the items that i'm populating dynamically.

Here's the image of what i've achieved so far...

[image: my current UI]

Here's the image of what i'm trying to achieve...

[image: my target UI]

My item layout xml

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/hollow_white_background"
        android:id="@+id/foodItemName"
        android:text="PIZZA"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGray300"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />
```

Please Help!

Comment: Please provide item layout xml and code you used for configuring GridLayoutManager.

Comment: Looking at your target UI I think you cannot get it by using a RecyclerView with standard layout manager. You need some kind of FlowLayout. There are many implementations available. For example [here](https://github.com/thetonrifles/android-tags-selector) it is a repository of mine including something similar.

Comment: Perhaps a FlowLayout is what you're looking for. See https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout or https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout.

Comment: Apparently here's a FlowLayout that can be filled by a RecyclerView.Adapter http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3113?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Android_Arsenal+%28The+Android+Arsenal%29

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file, add android:numColumns="auto_fit" and android:stretchmode="columnWidth" attributes for your GridView. First attribute decides how many columns there should be depending on the screen size, and second attribute decides what to do with the extra space left, which in this case increases the column widths.

Comment: have done that already, still it shows only two columns with my items aligned to the left,  doesn't handle extra space. What i want is when my item's width is small, then it should display like 3 columns or more and when width is large, then it should display 1 or 2 columns automatically!

Comment: @AyushMaurya well, those attributes should do exactly what you need. Can you update the question with your current xml file?

Comment: <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/guideText"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/foodItemGridList"></GridView> this  is the xml i was using, and question is still the same.

Comment: I think problem occurs because you are setting a specific Button (or TextView, whatever those are) width. Try making the width for each Button "wrap_content".

Comment: Nope, it's "wrap_content" only.

Comment: @AyushMaurya I advice you to put the .xml layout file and any related java file to your main question. That's as far as I can help with the given data.

Comment: Yeah, what you need cannot be achieved with GridView I think. Try something like this: https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` as LayoutManager of `RecyclerView` with fixed `width` of `item_layout.xml`

Comment: StaggeredGridLayoutManager affects rows, not columns!